# asynctask sharing between activities

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app downloads files (5-12MB a piece) and accesses them from external storage. Since the download takes a minute or two when one isn't on WiFi, I'd like to be able to start the download before the user gets to the Activity where they'll want it, so that they don't have to wait.

It seemed like AsyncTask was the best way to go, but then I realized that future activities (to my understanding) won't be able to check on the progress of the AsyncTask itself, the best they can do is keep checking to see if the file is readable... but what if the task is still running or lost network connectivity and needs to be retried?

It seems like a waste to indiscriminately recreate the AsyncTask and download the file again if it'd be finished soon.

Is there a way to access the AsyncTask (in particular, its status) from a future activity, or is there a better paradigm I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a service which downloads what you need in the background.
After its finished, you can tell your app via intent that the content is ready and stop the service via stopSelf(). Therefore your download continues all the time, even on homescreens.
So make sure you create a notification to tell the user and give him the chance to cancel. :)

Edit: And of course you can use a task inside the service. Since services don't spawn their own threads thats probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: For a background thread in a `Service`, consider `IntentService`.

Comment: I'm looking at IntentService, but I don't see a way to check on the status of the service. I can have it send notifications, but how would I have the UI thread check to see if it's still running?

Answer (score 2):

There is a cool explanation on how to design apps for such kind of purposes - [Developing Android REST client applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).

Comment: Link is broken.